# NSMutableArray in picker? (downPicker)

Tags: ios, nsarray, uipickerview

I have just implemented downPicker project from github into my app: https://github.com/Darkseal/DownPicker

The implementation is pretty much straightforward:

```
NSMutableArray* data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     [data addObject:@"a"];
     [data addObject:@"b"];
     [data addObject:@"c"];
     [data addObject:@"d"];

  _downPicker =  [[DownPicker alloc] initWithTextField:text withData:data];
```

But. My problem occurs when I try to fill the downPicker with another NSArray (items) via the code:

```
   NSMutableArray *dataTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:items, nil];
_downPicker =  [[DownPicker alloc] initWithTextField:text withData:dataTest];
```

This does not work. Nothing happens when I click the picker in the app? How come?

Regards

Comment: items is yiur NSArray or NSMUtable Array]

Comment: The problem isn't that the items array isn't mutable. The DownPicker init-method just calls for an NSArray, the problem must be something else. Can you provide more info about the items variable? Where does it come from? How is it set up? I'm guessing that the items array is either nil or does not have NSString components. (This would cause this exact behavior). Also make sure that the "text"-textField works/is retained.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your array by this way

```
 NSMutableArray *dataTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:items, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to reload your `UIPickerView` by calling

```
    [pickerview reloadAllComponents];
```

This will refresh all the content of your picker view.